# maintaing consistent layout wordpress dashboard

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin, admin

I am developing a functionality in WordPress so that once user updated any information admin  can approve/reject the information only after which it should get published in the front users,in specific terms functionality is much similar to e,g Comment approval.
i am new to PHP as well Word press, though i have developed the functionality and its working fine.
but i have created simple table in the dashboard where admin can see the things he/she needs to approve/reject.
i want to give it a consistent look like other functionality in word-press
e.g 
Comment

1. Admin can do bulk operations delete/approve with the build in panel.
2. Admin can quick edit/delete any individual comment

what i observe that there seems to be a single design pattern on which this is implemented as i can see same type of features for post/pages or any other place in dashboard where items are being displayed in list.

is there a way to achieve this.i will appreciate if some one help me to understand this.

attaching a screen shot for better clarification.

[image: common navigation area]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the WP_List_Table class. There is an example of how to use it in the .org plugin repository that you can use as a base for creating your own implementation: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-list-table-example/

Comment: Yes, i figure it out but still not sure how to use it in a right way.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that?

Comment: What all i mean is that i analyses how comment are being displayed in the dashboard and than i came to know about the WP_List_Table class but being new to php and word-press i am not sure how i can use that in my case.

Comment: The example plugin will show you how to extend the WP_List_Table class for whatever data you want, which includes bulk actions and filters. If you're new to PHP and WordPress, this is kind of a tough place to start.

Comment: Also, a custom post type would automatically have a list table that you could then extend. I'm trying to stick to your original question in my answer, but that's something to think about as well.

Comment: That was more than helpful..Thanks.Can u point me some way to use build in Ajax capabilities of wordpress?

Comment: Please search for previous questions and/or make a new one.